# How to acces to parent object in event listener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects

I need to access the parent object (not `window`) into an event listener.

Actually I get `window` with `self`, and the `WebSocket` object (event listener target) with `this`. I want to get the `ScratchCloud` object (parent).

Here is the JS code:

```js
var ScratchCloud = function(url, user, project) {
  "use strict";
  this.socket = new WebSocket(url); // Create socket

  this.ws_status = function() {
    var status = this.socket.readyState;
    var message = "Scratch Cloud Data Socket (";
    switch (status) {
      case 0:
        message += "Connecting";
      case 1:
        message += "Open";
      case 2:
        message += "Closing";
      case 3:
        message += "Closed";
    }
    message += ")"
    return message;
  }

  this.ws_log = function(message, func, symbol) {
    if (!func) {
      func = console.log;
    }
    if (symbol) {
      func(this.ws_status(), symbol, message);
    } else {
      func(this.ws_status() + ":", message);
    }
  };

  this.ws_open = function(event) {
    console.log(self === window);
    self.ws_log();
    var handshake = {
      method: "handshake",
      user: user,
      project: project
    };
    handshake = JSON.stringify(handshake) + "\n";
    self.ws_log(handshake, null, ">>");
    event.target.send(handshake);
    self.ws_log();
  }

  this.ws_error = function(event) {
    this.ws_log(console.error, event, ">>");
  };

  this.ws_message = function(event) {
    this.ws_log(console.log, event, ">>");
  };
  this.ws_close = this.ws_message;

  this.socket.onopen = this.ws_open;
  this.socket.onerror = this.ws_error;
  this.socket.onmessage = this.ws_message;
  this.socket.onclose = this.ws_close;
};
new ScratchCloud("wss://clouddata.scratch.mit.edu/", "<user-name>", "<scratch-project>");
```

How to access the `ScratchCloud` instance in the `ws_open` function? I searched about `this` and `self` but I can't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried `const ScratchCloud = this;` after `"use strict"` and then referencing it that way from `ws_open`?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the problem is `this`. First, you have learned about `this` in JS. When you invoke the function with `self` it is not working and accessing the `window` object. And when you use `this` then, you are calling `WebSocket` object. Right?

If you want to make `this` to use `ScratchCloud` function, you have to `bind` the `this` explicitly with `ScratchCloud` function. The following resources will help you understand explicit binding in JS:

- [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)
- [Understanding the "this" keyword, call, apply, and bind in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zE9iro4r918)
- [Javascript ‘This’. Who Is This?](https://medium.com/swlh/javascript-this-ac28f8e0f65d#:%7E:text=Explicit%20binding%20%7C%20Indirect%20invocation,are%20passed%20after%20the%20object.)
- [The JavaScript `this` Keyword + 5 Key Binding Rules Explained for JS Beginners](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-this-keyword-binding-rules/)

Hope the above will help you.